# Creating Groupby-like dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make a daily table of team stats and want to create a data frame where every team would have a row on every date. I tried doing it with counting and then repetitive joining and it gets all messy so I was wondering if there is a simpler solution like a function.

[image: Structure]

Comment: `df.groupby(['date', 'team'])...`

Comment: That's just plain groupby, my question is not that at all... I have 2 series and I want to create a data frame as it is described in the pic above. Please read beyond the title before replying.

Comment: Please post a question that makes sense. [MCVE]

Comment: It isn't a problem for solving, I'm just asking for a function. I don't want to argue anyways, @Guinther Kovalski answered it, thanks for the time anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that is what you want, but it seens like `pandas.melt()` is the case:

reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-melt/

Comment: It does the job but it messes up the sorting and since my index column is a date column that isn't datetime it is complicated to sort so I found out I could use stack() instead. I just transposed teams series and then duplicated it and concatenated it with dates and then stacked: